# Select Case Fall through with Not Condition in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement, conditional-statements, select-case

How to Add Not condition in the below select case.

Is <> works for single value, and 'To' works for a Range but the value are specific values there are not series of numbers. Is it possible to use select case in this scenario, or do i have to switch to if-else. Ex: i don't want case to execute when value is 0 and 3

```
           Select value
             case 0,1,2,3
           End Select
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question...

Why can't you just write the example code like so:

```
Select Case value
    Case 1, 2
        DoWork()
End Select
```

Nothing gets executed when `value = 0` or `value = 3`. The series of values provided to a `Case` statement doesn't have to be sequential.

---

**Update in response to comment:**

I would write that like this, taking advantage of the `Case Else` label:

```
Select Case myComboBox.SelectedIndex
    Case 1, 5, 8
        'The suggestion is acceptable, so process it
        DoWork()
    Case Else
        'The suggestion is invalid, so show an error
        MessageBox.Show("You cannot select that option. " & _
                        "Please choose options 1, 5, or 8 instead.", _
                        "Invalid Selection", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Select
```

Of course, if you don't actually have any "work" to be done in the case that the user selects the *correct* value, there seems little point in using a `Select Case` statement at all. The cardinal rule should be to **use whichever makes your code the clearest** and easiest to understand. There's little validity to the suspicion that `Select Case` is faster than an `If` statement—the compiler is smart enough to produce virtually equivalent results in almost every case.

Comment: Lets say 1,2,3,4...n aren't just values and they have meaning lets say they are the IDs from a drop-down/combo-box list and user selects a value. Lets say user is only allowed to select when its 1,5,8 and else show a message. How do u put that in a single case statement?

Comment: @user: I updated my answer with another code example. Does that help any?

Comment: I have thought about this as well, but just wanted to know if it can be done in single case statement . like If Not (1,5,8) then showMessagebox() .Instead of If (1,5,8) DoWork() Else ShowMessagebox().

Comment: @user: No. You can't do that. And there's absolutely no reason to do so, either. VB.NET is the only language that supports the `Case 1, 2, 3` syntax. You can't even write that in C#. You need `If (i = 1) OrElse (i = 5) OrElse (i = 8) Then`. What do you think is **wrong** with that, exactly?

Comment: just wanted to know if it was possible that's all.

Comment: @CodyGray you probably know it, but that is just plain wrong. C# Does support something like the `Case 1,2,3` , because there is a fallthrough and you have to break the switch manually.

Comment: @Mafii Well, that's true of C and C++, but C# doesn't have fall-through for case statements. You can certainly simulate it, but you'd have to use a goto, and [who knows what kinds of bad things that might cause](https://xkcd.com/292/)!

Comment: @CodyGray Not sure wheter I misunderstood something - here's an example: http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AMpAI457TxJrrEDCA9gDZuoDGyYLEIYgHFUEVACcwXauFoBZKeJYgWAM2TM4ACwCG4gA45s+4ACM2UmFzY6QIGExgBvbDDcxX7k+ctMAFACUnm4u7mEwIADuYMhcWn4iyABqOmzAqIEBoeE5XLaoMAAMAFzBOe55IAUAjKXl4ZUFAEx19e4AkKbiqDoA1jht7gAmqKo6wGzIrYPtyFpKkTBiiwByLMgAkuj6nOiiaEMAogAeXKj6vPyBA4Me9QC+ZY9hZd4WXDCQyDDHzlCoyEw9xgAF4YABWG5uMqmFjsGBoFBQu5eSQANx0aE+EG+iRSaQyQTC2XCYFUMD8iOQRJyJPqVNBCPE6WR5W6yGA4ggMAAzKy3M9ymUwuzOdzqsjHvcgA=== isn't that a switch fall-through?

Comment: @Mafii Um, I opened that, but I can't see any code anywhere. All of the boxes are blank. Refreshing or using another browser doesn't seem to help, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyway, I figure what you are probably talking about is that it does allow a single block to handle multiple cases, so `case 1: case 2: { … }` is perfectly fine. However, no block is actually allowed to fall through, so `case 1: { …}` cannot fall through to a subsequent `case 2: { … }`. They made this decision to avoid a common programming pitfall in C, at the expense of making Duff's Device impossible to code!

Comment: @CodyGray weird, well yes, this is what I'm talking about. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Cody wrote I would go with:

```
Select Case value
    Case 1, 2
        DoWork()
    Case 0 ,3               
        'nothing to do, only log if needed
    Case Else
        Debug.Fail("Please provide a logical path for all possible values")
End Select
```

The extra branches are just to clarify the intent of the code and to guard against future changes.

Answer (score 0):

I often combine SELECT/CASE with IF/END IF. The first one to catch a range, then second one to do similar things with the range, but maybe with small differences.

```
    Dim Result As Integer = 1
    Select Case Result
        Case 0 To 3
            SaveOrder()
            '0 to 3 is success 
            If Result <> 0 AndAlso Result <> 3 Then
                '1 and 2 = Everything ok
                SendCustomerMesage(0)
            Else
                '0 and 3 = Order OK, but no stock in storage
                SendCustomerMesage(1)
            End If

        Case 4 To 8
            '4 to 8 is error 
            InformCustomer(value)
        Case Else
            HandleError(value)
    End Select
```

Comment: A reasonable example, certainly, so pardon my nitpicking. But the real question that comes to mind is why you use return values to indicate errors. Unless this is really low-level code, exceptions are probably a better option. And even if you *do* return error codes, definitely use an enum for readability's sake.

Comment: @Cody it was only sample code I wrote up for this answer, not production code. ;)